# RealmId Not Coming Back in the OpenID Flow for Quickbooks Online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have a request to Quickbooks online in order to implement the proper single sign on (SSO) flow. I am using openid4java and getting back the first name, last name, and e-mail address just fine, but no realm id.

I used the published Intuit code as an example, my fetcher looks like this:
final FetchRequest fetch = FetchRequest.createFetchRequest();

```
    try {
        fetch.addAttribute("FirstName", "http://axschema.org/namePerson/first", true);
        fetch.addAttribute("LastName", "http://axschema.org/namePerson/last", true);
        fetch.addAttribute("Email", "http://axschema.org/contact/email", true);
        fetch.addAttribute("RealmId", "http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId", true);
    } catch (MessageException e) {
        mLogger.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Auth request looks like:

```
openid.ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
openid.claimed_id:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
openid.identity:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
openid.return_to:http://localhost:8888/qbopenid
openid.realm:http://localhost:8888/qbopenid
openid.assoc_handle:o5SH!IAAAACLd1tm9oBJwwIhLZnb4uHYSvphLvPKupx_kJsjquipfQQAAAAEgqUSt5DXPSGwQ79I7lFlHh8gGWpBFaXdjr6diKdticDtCpv8EgpBpO3lDHIhT-275K8lDxZWoeLxqABigxYjf
openid.mode:checkid_setup
openid.ns.ext1:http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ext1.mode:fetch_request
openid.ext1.type.FirstName:http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
openid.ext1.type.LastName:http://axschema.org/namePerson/last
openid.ext1.type.Email:http://axschema.org/contact/email
openid.ext1.type.RealmId:http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId
openid.ext1.required:FirstName,LastName,Email,RealmId
```

But when the request is returned I don't see any mention of the realm id either in the request. It's almost like it goes missing. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the note here:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/0030_signing_into_and_out_of_intuit_from_within_your_app/sign-in/implement_sso_and_openid_in_your_app

This field can only be fetched when there is an active connection between the realm and the app and when the user is launching the application from the App Center or navigating to the application from the Blue Dot menu.

You will be returned the realm at the end of the OAuth flow to associate it to the access tokens.  It is not always returned by OpenID.

Comment: Yeah, this is super confusing, if you look at the single sign on docs for this it doesn't make this clear at all. The Java example in the docs specifically tries to use the realmid to authenticate the user.

Also the comment, "It's not always" is kind of odd because with software in general having code that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Correct, so do not depend on it coming back from OpenID.  Associate it with the user after the OAuth flow.

Comment: Does this also come through during the try/buy flow or how does one tell the difference between try/buy and a normal sign in with intuit? Thanks!

Comment: I think I already answered this on another thread you had this morning, but you can add a query parameter to the OpenID URL in your app settings.

Comment: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/829329-how-do-you-know-when-a-user-is-coming-from-apps-com-versus-using-the-login-with-intuit-button

Comment: Hi @PeterLavelle can I get realmid from apps.intuit.com -> get app now button -> authorize and -> our open id url?